# To generate a sequence of dates based on starting and ending dates

Tags: date, awk

Would like to generate consecutive dates based on `Start Date ($1)` and `End Date ($2)`.
Covered leap year also in example.

Input.txt

```
02-JUL-2015,04-JUL-2015
28-FEB-2016,02-MAR-2016
30-DEC-2013,01-JAN-2014
12-AUG-2012,14-AUG-2012
```

I have tried like below command and in-complete :

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
BEGIN {FS=","}
{
    split($1,s,"-")
    split($2,e,"-")
    st=mktime(s[3] " "(index("JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC",s[2])+2)/3" " s[1] " 0 0 0")
    et=mktime(e[3] " "(index("JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC",e[2])+2)/3" " e[1] " 0 0 0")
    for (i=st;i<=et;i+=60*60*24) print strftime("%d-%b-%Y",i)
}
```

Desired Output:

```
02-JUL-2015
03-JUL-2015
04-JUL-2015
28-FEB-2016
29-FEB-2016
01-MAR-2016
02-MAR-2016
30-DEC-2013
31-DEC-2013
01-JAN-2014
12-AUG-2012
13-AUG-2012
14-AUG-2012
```

Please suggest !!!

Comment: I get a different error that can be fixed by moving `BEGIN { FS="," }` out of the catch-all block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `print strftime("%d-%b-%Y",i)` to `print toupper(strftime("%d-%b-%Y",i))`.

Get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: He likes to be called Aharon Robbins! `:P`

Comment: The emails I get from him are signed "Arnold" and more importanly his name on the book as author is "Arnold" (see http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033820.do). I did miss the 2nd `b` in his surname though, corrected now.

Comment: I was just messing with you! :)